# Changing the player after a coin is taken

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm programming a game where two players each need to pick one or two coins until all the coins are gone, changing players after picking. The game starts by giving the game rules and giving an option to play 1vs1 or 1vscomputer (this option not yet done). After choosing option 1 (1vs1) the game starts randomly choosing player 1 or 2 as the beginner. Via the buttons you can pick one or two coins which are subtracted from the total (so far so good). Now after you have picked one or two coins the player is supposed to change... only this doesn't happen.

```
import tkinter
import random
from time import sleep

def toonStartscherm():
    keuzescherm.pack_forget()
    spelerscherm.pack_forget()
    startscherm.pack()

def toonKeuzescherm():
    keuzescherm.pack()
    startscherm.pack_forget()
    spelerscherm.pack_forget()

def spelOptie1():
    keuzescherm.pack_forget()
    startscherm.pack_forget()
    spelerscherm.pack()

def randomSpeler():
    global beginnende_speler
    if beginnende_speler == '1':
        beginnende_speler = '2'
    else:
        beginnende_speler = '1'
    return beginnende_speler

def Munt1():
    global aantal_munten
    eenMunt = 1
    aantal_munten -= eenMunt
    munten_over.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
    if aantal_munten == 0:
        beurt_speler.configure(text='Hoera!')
        munten_over.configure(text='Speler' + beginnende_speler + (' heeft gewonnen'))

def Munt2():
    global aantal_munten
    tweeMunt = 2
    aantal_munten -= tweeMunt
    munten_over.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
    if aantal_munten == 0:
        beurt_speler.configure(text='Hoera!')
        munten_over.configure(text='Speler' + beginnende_speler + (' heeft gewonnen'))

nim_spel = tkinter.Tk()

global aantal_munten
aantal_munten = 7

global beginnende_speler
beginnende_speler = random.choice(['1', '2'])

startscherm = tkinter.Frame(master=nim_spel)
startscherm.pack()
start_welkom = tkinter.Label(startscherm, text= 'Welkom bij het NIM spel! \nHieronder volgende de spelregels.')
start_welkom.pack()
start_uitleg = tkinter.Label(startscherm, text= 'Het spel NIM start met 7 munten, elke speler mag één of twee munten pakken. \n De speler die de laatste munt pakt verliest!')
start_uitleg.pack() # zet uitleg automatisch in venster
doorgaan_knop = tkinter.Button(startscherm, text = 'Ik snap de regels!', fg = 'green', command = toonKeuzescherm) # maakt knop en laat stoppen
doorgaan_knop.pack(side = 'bottom')

keuzescherm = tkinter.Frame(master=nim_spel)
keuzescherm.pack()
keuze_opties = tkinter.Label(keuzescherm, text='Het NIM spel kan op twee manieren gespeeld worden. \n Optie 1: Tegen elkaar \n Optie 2: Tegen de computer')
keuze_opties.pack() # zet opties automatisch in venster
keuze_vraag = tkinter.Label(keuzescherm, text='Voor welke optie kies je?')
keuze_vraag.pack()
optie_1 = tkinter.Button(keuzescherm, text = 'Optie 1', fg = 'green', command = spelOptie1) # maakt knop en laat stoppen
optie_1.pack(side = 'left')
optie_2 = tkinter.Button(keuzescherm, text = 'Optie 2', fg = 'red', command = keuzescherm.quit) # maakt knop en laat stoppen
optie_2.pack(side = 'right')

spelerscherm = tkinter.Frame(master=nim_spel)
spelerscherm.pack()
beurt_speler = tkinter.Label(spelerscherm, text='Speler ' + (beginnende_speler) + ' is aan de beurt!')
beurt_speler.pack()
munten_over = tkinter.Label(spelerscherm, text='Er zijn nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
munten_over.pack()
pak_1_munt = tkinter.Button(spelerscherm, text = '1 munt', fg = 'blue', command = Munt1)
pak_1_munt.pack(side = 'left')
pak_2_munt = tkinter.Button(spelerscherm, text = '2 munten', fg = 'blue', command = Munt2)
pak_2_munt.pack(side = 'right')

toonStartscherm()
nim_spel.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `print()` (in many places) to check values in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem/mistake. it's called "print debugging"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with tkinter and how its looping works but I see you have a function randomSpeler() that is never called in the code. In both Munt1() and Munt2() you have an if statement checking if the number of coins is 0, but not an else statement for in case there are more than 0 coins. Perhaps you could add that condition and call randomSpeler() to change the player from there?

Answer (score 0):

As @higherer already said you have to call `randomSpeler()` to change player.

You have to also change text in `beurt_speler` to display correct player

See three comments in this part of code

```
def randomSpeler():
    global beginnende_speler

    if beginnende_speler == '1':
        beginnende_speler = '2'
    else:
        beginnende_speler = '1'

    # display correct player
    beurt_speler.config(text='Speler ' + beginnende_speler + ' is aan de beurt!')

    return beginnende_speler

def Munt1():
    global aantal_munten

    aantal_munten -= 1
    munten_over.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + str(aantal_munten) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
    if aantal_munten == 0:
        beurt_speler.configure(text='Hoera!')
        munten_over.configure(text='Speler' + beginnende_speler + ' heeft gewonnen')
    else:
        # change player
        randomSpeler()

def Munt2():
    global aantal_munten

    aantal_munten -= 2
    munten_over.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + str(aantal_munten) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
    if aantal_munten == 0:
        beurt_speler.configure(text='Hoera!')
        munten_over.configure(text='Speler' + beginnende_speler + ' heeft gewonnen')
    else:
        # change player
        randomSpeler()
```